# how can i request an html page in an "HTTP request", and asking only for some regex or specific html tag in it?

Tags: python, html, http, httpwebrequest

is there any header or method in http protocol which allows you to get specific tag from an html resource for example i would like to get all the  tag in this python request, instead of all the html page. is there any thing i can do while setting the request which is supported by the http protocol 1.1v or 1.0v ?

```
import httplib

def printText(txt):
    lines = txt.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        print line.strip()



httpServ = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
httpServ.connect()
httpServ.request('GET',"/search?q=blabla")

response = httpServ.getresponse()
if response.status == httplib.OK:
   printText (response.read())
if response.status != httplib.OK:
   print "NOT OK" ,  response.status
httpServ.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure you need to load the entire HTML file before you can parse through it for the target elements.

Comment: And then you can use something like BeautifulSoup to parse and grab what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP headers let you specify that you want *html* but don't let you search for a specific part of the  tag tree.

If the server accepts ranges, then you can pull down the html in discrete blocks (at byte intervals, but not corresponding to the beginning or end of various tags).  Then you can search each block until you find the tag of interest.

Otherwise, you'll likely have to download the whole page and run *lmxl*, *http5lib*, or *BeautifulSoup* on the result.

Good luck with your quest.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to get the entire page. The HTTP protocol does not provide a means of downloading a partial page by HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't make such a request via http, you can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a python module that will parse the html for you.