# How to load specific URL until get the desired result?

Tags: python, windows, urllib

How can I load a specific URL, or a specific content of it, until get the result I want?

For example, I need only the second line from a website, and using urllib.urlopen I have to load the entire site to search what I want, which is in the second line.

thank you

edit:
Is not that I can't read the lines, is because I have to load several pages, and stopping when I get the result will make the process much faster.

here is the code I'm using to do the job so far:

> ```
> c = 'http://www.URL.com'
> b = urllib.urlopen(c)
> for line in b:
>     if ('var codItem' in line):
>         d = line.find('= "') + 3
>         e = line.find('";', d)
>         Cod = line[d:e]
> ```

Comment: Why can't you read line by line using `urllib.urlopen`? Call `readline`-method on the returned object.

Comment: How are you using `urlopen`? The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) say that it supports `readline()`, which should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: if the data isn't newline separated, you will not be able to use `readline()`

Answer (score 1):

Pulling down an entire webpage is the norm; however, some web servers support range requests to let you pull down a specific range of bytes until you've found what you're looking for.

See this related SO question:  [how can i request an html page in an "HTTP request", and asking only for some regex or specific html tag in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684051)

This Accept-Ranges HTTP header is described in section 14.5 of  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly possible with HTTP. You can issue `Range` headers to fetch only a specific chunk of bytes from a page, but then you'd need to know what the byte offset of your desired content is. Best to just fetch the whole page and extract what you want with DOM operations.

Answer (score 0):

reading the [urllib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen). You are able to put a size to f.read(). This allows you to pull down a certain amount of data out of the stream and not mess with the other bits of data. Seeing as you are opening a TCP stream, the data will still be sent across the connection but by only reading a section of the data, you'll only have to deal with the bytes `read`

Answer (score -1):

Use the [break](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement:

```
 c = 'http://www.URL.com'
 b = urllib.urlopen(c)
 for line in b:
     if ('var codItem' in line):
         d = line.find('= "') + 3
         e = line.find('";', d)
         Cod = line[d:e]
         break
```